# Jquery Mobile pageshow event firing twice

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I currently have a mobile site I am building and I am having trouble with integrating a custom JQuery widget. For some reason the the pageshow event is firing twice for whichever page is loaded first.

For ease of understanding I have created two HTML pages

**Page 1**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>One</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reloadPage = true;
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="default">
    <div data-role="page" id="content-one">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="one-content">
            One<br/>
            <a href="two.html">back to two</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($, undefined) {
            $.widget("test.stuff", {
                _create : function() {
                    console.log("create");
                },
                _init : function() {
                    console.log("_init");
                },
                destroy: function () {
                    this.element.empty();
                    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageshow", "#content-one", function () { 
            console.log("pageshow1");
            $("#content-one").stuff({});
        });
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#content-one", function () { 
            console.log("pagebeforeshow1");
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Two</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reloadPage = true;
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="default">
    <div data-role="page" id="content-two">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            Two<br/>
            <a href="one.html">back to one</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("pageshow", "#content-two", function () { 
            console.log("pageshow2");
        });
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#content-two", function () { 
            console.log("pagebeforeshow2");
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To recreate load page one first, navigate to page two using link, then navigate to page one using link.

When page one is loaded again the pageshow event is fired twice. I have the reloadPage set to true as I have dynamic content for my pages and I cannot serve cached pages.

I very well could be using the events incorrectly.

Comment: `reloadPage` is deprecated and no longer can be set as an _option_. Instead use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page.html", { reload: true });` to load page and reload it programmatically. Also, `pageshow` is deprecated but still functioning, use `$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () { code });`.

Comment: If I should not use reloadPage What mechanism should I use to ensure each page is loaded each time and is not pulled from cache? I want this to be the default functionality for all navigation.

Comment: `reload` instead of `reloadPage`.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting your `$(document).on("pageshow",...)` with `$(document).one("pageshow", ...)`, which restricts the event to one call http://api.jquery.com/one/.

The problem is that using `on` in the inline script creates a new event each time the page is loaded. So the first time you load the page, the inline script is executed and the pageshow event is triggered. The second time a new event is triggered again, but the first one is still listening to content-one pageshow. In fact, if you repeat the process you'll see the log three, four, ... times.

Another option could be to create a script in the head section which sets up all required triggers in `$(document).on("pageshow", "#content-one", ...), $(document).on("pageshow", "#content-two", ...)`. In this case, the script will only be initialized once, so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted about 2 hours trying to do all the fixes on here and other sites. I gave up and put an if statement in their to prevent it from firing again

```
var hasDownload = false;
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage",function(event){
    if (hasDownload === false) {
        hasDownload = true;
        // do some work
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  to remove the page on hide event, like so :

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reloadPage = true;
        $(docuement).on('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
            $(event.target).remove();
        });
    });
```

Remenber that if you don't disable ajax, all request will be with AJAX